# What does ampersand mean in a selector name?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I retrieve `$(".q&a");` ?

Chrome is telling me: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .q&a`

I've tried `"q\&a"` and `"q&amp;a"` with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out at the end of writing the question. Hope this helps someone else.

`$("q\\&a");`

Comment: Right. The first backslash just makes the next character literal (unless it's part of an escape sequence like `\n`), you need a second one to make the backslash literal.